# How to create a signature of higher trust level in GnuPG?

Tags: gnupg

A friend of mine signed my GPG key:

```
% gpg --list-sigs 0xAAAAAAAA
pub   4096R/AAAAAAAA 2011-03-14
uid                  Alice <alice@example.com>
sig 3        AAAAAAAA 2011-03-14  Alice <alice@example.com>
sig 2        BBBBBBBB 2011-10-21  Bob <bob@example.com>
sub   4096R/DDDDDDDD 2011-03-14
sig          AAAAAAAA 2011-03-14  Alice <alice@example.com>
```

Whenever I sign a key (using `gpg --sign-key`) `sig` instead of `sig 2` appears. E.g.:

```
% gpg --list-sigs bob@example.com 
pub   2048R/BBBBBBBB 2011-07-10
uid                  Bob <bob@example.com>
sig 3        BBBBBBBB 2011-07-10  Bob <bob@example.com>
sig          AAAAAAAA 2011-10-21  Alice <alice@example.com>
sub   3072R/CCCCCCCC 2011-07-10
sig          BBBBBBBB 2011-07-10  Bob <bob@example.com>
```

What is the difference and how can I select between `sig` and `sig 2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the certification level to indicate how carefully you verified the key owner's identity.
Available levels are:
    0: no indication;
    1: personal belief but no verification, useful for signing pseudonymous IDs;
    2: casual verification;
    3: extensive verification.

Per default gpg doesn't ask for this and aways uses level 2.
To use another level when signing a key use the switch --ask-cert-level either on command line or in your gpg.conf.

See here http://tanguy.ortolo.eu/blog/article9/pgp-signature-infos

Comment: Thank you. I did not find `--ask-cert-level` when searching for this in the man page (looked everywhere for "sign[ing]"). Although according to the man page the default seems to be level 0, not level 2.